# Sencha ExtJS. Cannot send POST request on cross-domain with Ext.Ajax.request

Tags: ajax, extjs, cross-domain

I have backend with POST functionality (so JSONP is not working).
Backend sends `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` correctly (jQuery.ajax works successfully).
But I cannot send request using Ext.Ajax.request

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: 'http://myurl',
  method: 'POST',
  cors: true,
  success: function () {
    alert('success');
  },
  failure: function () {
    alert('failure');
  }
});
```

In debug console I see OPTIONS method

[image]

Where is my mistake?

```
Ext.getVersion()
```

> version: "5.0.1.1255"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you will have to set `useDefaultXhrHeader` to `false` also in your ajax request,like below.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: 'http://myurl',
  method: 'POST',
  cors: true,
  useDefaultXhrHeader : false,
  success: function () {
    alert('success');
  },
  failure: function () {
    alert('failure');
  }
});
```