# Pagination is not updating the view when the next button is clicked

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

The total number of rows is correctly showing in pagination but Pagination is not updating the view when the next button is clicked.

I'm new to Sencha. In Mysql, I'm returning all rows. So that I can limit in client side. If I limit the rows in backend, I cannot have all the rows in client side.

View: List.js

```
/*** This view is an example list of people.
     */



Ext.define('CRUD.view.main.List', {
            extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
            xtype: 'home',
            requires: [
                'CRUD.store.Personnel'
            ],

            title: 'Heroes',
            plugins: [
                Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                    clicksToEdit: 1
                })
            ],
            layout: 'fit',
            fullscreen: true,
            store: {
                type: 'personnel',
            },
            columns: [
                { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', sortable: true, flex: 1 },
                { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', sortable: true, flex: 1 },
                { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone', sortable: true, flex: 1 }
            ],
            bbar: {
                store: {
                    type: 'personnel',
                },
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                displayInfo: true
            },
            // columns: [
            //     { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1 },
            //     { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
            //     { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone', flex: 1 }
            // ],

            listeners: {
                select: 'onItemSelected',
            },
        });
```

Store: Personnel.js

```
Ext.define('CRUD.store.Personnel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

        alias: 'store.personnel',

        model: 'CRUD.model.User',

        id: 'list',

        fields: [
            'name', 'email', 'phone'
        ],

        // data: [
        //     { name: 'Jean Luc', email: "jeanluc.picard@enterprise.com", phone: "555-111-1111" },
        //     { name: 'Worf', email: "worf.moghsson@enterprise.com", phone: "555-222-2222" },
        //     { name: 'Deanna', email: "deanna.troi@enterprise.com", phone: "555-333-3333" },
        //     { name: 'Data', email: "mr.data@enterprise.com", phone: "555-444-4444" }
        // ],
        autoLoad: {
            start: 0,
            limit: itemsPerPage
        },
        buffered: true,
        pageSize: itemsPerPage,
        remoteSort: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp', //cross domain calls - json parser
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/list',
            enablePaging: true,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                totalProperty: 'total'
            },

        },
        // proxy: {
        //     type: 'memory',
        //     reader: {
        //         type: 'json',
        //     }
        // },

});
```

Answer (score 1):

bbar: {
       **store: {
                    type: 'personnel',
                },**
      xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
      displayInfo: true
},

I have removed store inside bbar and it works. Thanks for being cooperative.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using the store, ExtJS will do a request every time you change the page, sending the page number parameter to the URL set to the store.

If you want to do client-side pagination using ExtJS, you must set your store's proxy type to `memory`, load your data into the store and then ExtJS Grid will handle pagination as you expect.

Do an `Ext.Ajax.Request` like that:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/list',
    success: function(response) {
        dataStore.setProxy({
            type: "memory",
            enablePaging: true,
            data: Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText) //here you need to adapt to your response structure
        });
        dataStore.load();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually, there is a Cross Domain problem. So I'm using JsonP. Ajax is not working for Cross domain request.

Answer (score 0):

For cross domain, you can make a call to **Ext.data.JsonP.request()** method and process the response as shown in the code below:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
        url: 'data1.json',
        success: function (response) {
            var myData = [];
            Ext.Array.forEach(response.data, function (item) {
                myData.push({
                    name: item.name,
                    email: item.email,
                    phone: item.phone
                });
            });
            store.setProxy({
                type: "memory",
                enablePaging: true,
                data: myData
            });
            store.load();
        }
    });
```

Check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27go) for complete working example.

Comment: For me, success is not working inside or outside proxy, I have given alert or console.log but dosen't goes inside Success function. You are using Ext.data.JsonP.request, Please show me how to write using proxy.

Comment: I used Ext.data.JsonP.request() because your requirement was to do client-side pagination. For this, the example fiddle first fetched the complete data set and then used the memory proxy for pagination.  If you want to send partial data on every click of  next button, from cross domain , then this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27go) does it. It uses jsonp proxy and works perfectly but pagination does not work because there is no server-side code to process the paging information in request. (Back-end code sends the complete data set.)

Comment: [Here's](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27n6) another example. Reference (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/grid/paging.html)

Comment: JsonP works with GET method only so please verify this for your code. If you have Post method  then backend must send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header correctly. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682785/sencha-extjs-cannot-send-post-request-on-cross-domain-with-ext-ajax-request).

Comment: And if you want to have local paging only then please refer this [post](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?71532-Ext-ux-data-PagingStore-v0-5)